# Link para cancelar edição ainda aparece como 'Cancel'

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Este é bem simples.

Ao editar uma pergunta ou resposta, o `label` do link de cancelar ainda aparece como `cancel`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]